# Yarn installation : EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: yarnpkg

I am currently experiencing a crash since the beginning of the morning with the following command: `yarn install`

I have this error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read".
```

here is what my yarn-error.log file contains:

```
Trace: 
  Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

npm manifest: 
  {
    "dependencies": {
      "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
      "jquery": "^3.2.0",
      "lightbox2": "^2.9.0",
      "semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
      "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.22.0",
      "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
      "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
      "dedent": "^0.7.0",
      "eslint": "^4.19.1",
      "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
      "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^4.0.0",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
      "fast-async": "^6.3.7",
      "gulp": "^4.0.0",
      "gulp-chug": "^0.5",
      "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
      "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
      "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
      "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
      "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
      "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
      "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
      "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.5",
      "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
      "rollup": "^0.60.7",
      "rollup-plugin-babel": "^3.0.4",
      "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^9.1.3",
      "rollup-plugin-inject": "^2.0.0",
      "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.3.0",
      "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^4.0.0",
      "upath": "^1.1.0",
      "yargs": "^6.4.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "build": "gulp build",
      "gulp": "gulp build",
      "lint": "yarn lint:js",
      "lint:js": "eslint gulpfile.babel.js",
      "watch": "gulp watch"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git+https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius.git"
    },
    "author": "PaweÅ‚ JÄ™drzejewski",
    "license": "MIT"
  }

yarn manifest: 
  No manifest

Lockfile: 
  No lockfile
```

I would like to know how to unblock this situation. I have this result since I try to configure sylius on my server. Without this, my site does not have any elements of style